# Сохранение данных из запроса в Redux хранилище

Tags: reactjs, redux

необходимо получить информацию запросом (готово при помощи Axios) и сохранить её в **Redux** хранилище для дальнейшего использования в разных компонентах, как это сделать? Где правильно разместить функцию с запросом и как передать результат в хранилище? Может у кого то есть гайд или пример кода?

**О приложении**, это простой калькулятор криптовалют, а также система для постоянного мониторинга той же криптовалюты и отрисовки графика изменений курса.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можешь попробовать миделвер Redux-Thunk https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk он дает возможность работать с промисами, и довольно легкий в понимании

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
// добавляешь мидлевар
const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));
```

экшены:

```
export const fetchSomething = (someData) => {
    return dispatch => axios.get(url, someData).then(response => {
        dispatch({ type: 'SOME_TYPE', payload: response.data });
    });
}
```

и передаешь экшен в компонент

```
const mapDispatchToProps = {
    fetchSomething,
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SomeComponent);
```

Comment: Спасибо, попробую.

Comment: А как создать редьюсер для этой конструкции?

Comment: Редьюсер самый обычный, тут дело в экшене он подождет когда промис зареджектится или зарезолвится и выполнит диспатчь